# .DefaultIfEmpty() based on date values

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have an Entity Framework model `Schedule` that's mapped to a table `dbo.Schedule`. Two of the fields in `Schedule` are `hours` (`decimal`) and `week_ending` (`DateTime`).

I would like to output the data in the `Schedule` table to JSON like so:

```
{
   "week": [
         "2017-08-11",
         "2017-08-18",
         "2017-08-25",
         "2017-09-01"],
   "hours": [
         40,  
         40,
          0,
         30]
}
```

In other words, I would like to concatenate `week_ending` and `hours` results into just two arrays, where results are `grouped by` week, and insert a `0` value for `hours` when there are no records for that week.

I know `.DefaultIfEmpty()` can accomplish something like the latter, but I don't know how I would go about defining "empty" as "there is more than 7 days between two queried dates" (i.e. a week is missing). `week_ending` values are always Fridays, so they are always 7 days apart.

I'm not sure where to start with this... I have a fairly basic LINQ query like so (irrelevant `Where` clauses omitted):

```
var data =
  db.Schedules
    .OrderBy(s => s.week_ending)
    .Select(s => new
    { 
        week = s.week_ending,
        hours = s.hours
    });
```

which produces this JSON after serialization:

```
[
    {
        "week": "2017-08-11",
        "hours": 20
    },
    // I would like for this record to be grouped 
    // with the first into one "hours": 40 record
    {
        "week": "2017-08-11",
        "hours": 20
    },
    {
        "week": "2017-08-18",
        "hours": 40
    },
    // there is no "2017-08-25 record in the DB, 
    // but I would like for one to be printed with "hours": 0
    {
        "week": "2017-09-01",
        "hours": 30
    }
]
```

Comment: So you'd like to group weeks by how many hours long they were, and in calendar order, right ?

Comment: No, just by calendar order. 
The hours values I would like added together if there are multiple records for the same week. For instance, if I have two `Schedules` both with `week_ending =2017-08-11`, and one is `hours = 10` and the other is `hours = 30`, then the output would have a single record with `week = 2017-08-11` and `hours = 40`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider the following approach

1. Enumerate the aggregation of schedules matching the criteria between start/end dates
2. Identify and add missing dates, then order results
3. Create a `data` object to match desired output

Code might look as follows to leave `data` in desired format:

```
// Simulate linq connection
var db = new
{
    Schedules = new List<Schedule>
    {
        new Schedule() { hours = 40, week_ending = new DateTime(2017,8,11) },
        new Schedule() { hours = 20, week_ending = new DateTime(2017,8,18) }, // Simulating multiple records
        new Schedule() { hours = 20, week_ending = new DateTime(2017,8,18) }, // Simulating multiple records
        // No records for 8/25
        new Schedule() { hours = 30, week_ending = new DateTime(2017,9,1) },
    }
};

// Need a start/end date so you can generate missing weeks
var startDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 11);
var endDate = new DateTime(2017, 9, 1);

// Enumerate schedules from db
var schedules = db.Schedules // Add any other criteria besides date logic
    .Where(m => m.week_ending >= startDate && m.week_ending <= endDate)
    .GroupBy(m => m.week_ending)
    .Select(m => new Schedule() { week_ending = m.Key, hours = m.Sum(s => s.hours) })
    .AsEnumerable();

// Add missing dates
var results = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days)
    .Select(m => startDate.AddDays(m))
    .Where(m => m.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday) // Only end of week
    .Where(m => schedules.Any(s => s.week_ending == m) == false) // Add missing weeks
    .Select(m => new Schedule() { week_ending = m, hours = 0 })
    .Union(schedules)
    .OrderBy(m => m.week_ending);

// Enumerate the ordered schedules matching your criteria
var data = new
{
    week = results.Select(m => m.week_ending),
    hours = results.Select(m => m.hours)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Outline of approach:

- Sum existing hours for each week.
- Generate a range of dates, and then ...
- ... for each date in the range, generate an empty schedule with zero hours
- This list is then pruned, based on the summed hours above.
- Finally, the results are combined to give a complete list for the entire range.

.

```cs
// sample class
public class Schedule
{
    public DateTime week {get; set;}
    public int hours {get; set;}
}

// sample data
var scheduleTable = new List<Schedule>();

scheduleTable.Add(new Schedule() { week=new DateTime(2017,8,11), hours=20});
scheduleTable.Add(new Schedule() { week=new DateTime(2017,8,11), hours=20});
scheduleTable.Add(new Schedule() { week=new DateTime(2017,8,18), hours=30});

// Sum all hours that fall on the same week.
var summedSchedule = scheduleTable.GroupBy(
    x => x.week, 
    x => x.hours, 
    (key, g) => new Schedule() { week = key, hours = g.Sum() }
);

// Generate range of dates. You'll need to define the cut off point. Here,
// 10 weeks of dates are generated by adding 7 days successively to the
// starting date (the first date found from above)
var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => scheduleTable.First().week.AddDays(7 * x));

// Generate empty schedules, assigning zero hours to every week in the range.
var zeroSchedules = dates.Select(x => new Schedule() { week = x, hours = 0 });

// Pull out the dates for the weeks that have hours.
var fullWeeks = summedSchedule.Where(x => x.hours > 0).Select(x => x.week);

// Use the above list to pull out only the Schedule objects without hours.
var emptyWeeks = zeroSchedules.Where(x => !fullWeeks.Contains(x.week));

// The above list of zero-hour-weeks is then combined with the starting
// (summed) list of weeks that have hours.
var combined = new List<Schedule>();
combined.AddRange(emptyWeeks);
combined.AddRange(summedSchedule);
combined = combined.OrderBy(x => x.week).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem to solve: you can't query something that is not in the database, like missing weeks.

You'll need some time range, since otherwise there are really many fridays in your result... I'll define that range as two `DateTime`s `fromIncl` and `toExcl`.

The easy part: query the database already summing up the hours by week and put the result into a dictionary.

```
// SELECT week = sch.week_ending, hours = SUM(sch.hours)
// FROM dbo.Schedules sch
// WHERE sch.week_ending >= fromIncl AND sch.week_ending < toExcl
// GROUP BY sch.week_ending
var hoursByWeek = db.Schedules
    .Where(sch => sch.week_ending >= fromIncl && sch.week_ending < toExcl)
    .GroupBy(sch => sch.week_ending, (k, vs) => new { week = k, hours = vs.Sum(sch1 => sch1.hours) })
    .ToDictionary(sch => sch.week, sch => sch.hours);
```

Now for the missing weeks: you need to be able to enumerate them, because they may not be present in the database:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> EnumerateFridays(DateTime fromIncl, DateTime toExcl)
{
    fromIncl = fromIncl.Date; // just to be sure
    switch (fromIncl.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday: fromIncl = fromIncl.AddTicks(5 * TimeSpan.TicksPerDay); break;
        case DayOfWeek.Monday: fromIncl = fromIncl.AddTicks(4 * TimeSpan.TicksPerDay); break;
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday: fromIncl = fromIncl.AddTicks(3 * TimeSpan.TicksPerDay); break;
        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday: fromIncl = fromIncl.AddTicks(2 * TimeSpan.TicksPerDay); break;
        case DayOfWeek.Thursday: fromIncl = fromIncl.AddTicks(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay); break;
        // case DayOfWeek.Friday: break;
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday: fromIncl = fromIncl.AddTicks(6 * TimeSpan.TicksPerDay); break;
    }
    Debug.Assert(fromIncl.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday);
    for (; fromIncl < toExcl; fromIncl = fromIncl.AddTicks(7 * TimeSpan.TicksPerDay))
        yield return fromIncl;
}
```

Given another handy extension method:

```
public static TValue ValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
{
    TValue value;
    return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : defaultValue;
}
```

Your result is expressed as

```
MyAwesomeClass.EnumerateFridays(fromIncl, toExcl)
.Select(friday => new { week = friday, hours = hoursByWeek.ValueOrDefault(friday) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your original query as a basis, group the weeks, then find the first/last week in the range and generate a range of weeks, then left join the range onto the original data:

```
var groupeddata = from d in data
          group d by d.week into dg
          select new { week = dg.Key, hours = dg.Sum(d => d.hours)};

var beginDate = groupeddata.Select(d => d.week).Min();
var endDate = groupeddata.Select(d => d.week).Max();

var weeks = Enumerable.Range(0, (endDate-beginDate).Days / 7 + 1).Select(n => beginDate.AddDays(7*n)).ToList();

var ans = from w in weeks
          join s in groupeddata on w equals s.week into sj
          from s in sj.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new { week = w, hours = (s == null ? 0 : s.hours) };
```